# Windows 7: Recover password from Windows XP Mode

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp-mode, password-recovery

Are there any tricks to recovering the password from a virtual machine running Windows XP running in "Windows XP Mode" on Windows 7?

Comment: I assume it'd be the same as any normal XP machine. Get the LM hashes and crack them. Process of doing this, I can't remember.

Comment: did my answer help you enough for my answer to be accepted? I was just curious and wanted to make sure that you got the results you desired.

Answer (score 3):

I would download the tool found at the following web page. http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/cd100627.zip All you need to do is just boot to the disc and it will step you through a command line interface that will allow you to clear the password of the operating system. Most answers to the command line can be answered correctly with the default answer (by pressing Enter) If you need any help, please comment.

-Good Luck

Answer (score 2):

Just start it in safe mode, log in with Administrator and a blank password, and reset it from there. No need for a password reset disc.