# Enable network adapter before boot

Tags: windows, networking, windows-home-server

I accidentally disabled the network adapter on my headless Windows Home Server 2011. I would hook up a monitor to it, but I've been using RDP saved credentials for a couple of years, and no longer remember the password.

How can I reenable the adapter so I can remote in again?

Comment: Couldn't you just use the credentials that you use when you RDP? You can't enable the adapter over the network if the server isn't connected to the network.

Comment: @David Yes, if there were a way to view the password that Remote Desktop Connect has saved, I would be able to hook up a display and log in locally.

Comment: You will need to following the following link to assist you in finding the password. http://superuser.com/questions/307776/are-saved-remote-desktop-credentials-secure-on-the-local-machine It is impossible to enable the network adapter unless you have access to the machine. Sorry I asked you a question you answered in your initial question. I misread it the first time.

Comment: The only other option I know is to hack the password. I describe how to do this in the following link: http://superuser.com/a/207460/50697

Comment: @David Thank you, I just ran Network Password Recovery v1.33, and I can see my Windows credentials passwords (how RDP passwords are saved in Windows 8) plain as day! I will go this route, so would you mind making an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use [Network Password Recovery](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/network_password_recovery.html) to view your saved RDP password and then login locally to reenable the adapter. How it works is described in [this](https://superuser.com/a/350865/68111) SuperUser answer. It is impossible to enable the network adapter unless you have access to the physical machine machine otherwise.

The only other option I know is to hack the Windows password. I describe how to do this in the [this](https://superuser.com/a/207460/50697) SuperUser answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the tool [Remote Desktop Password](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/remote_desktop_password.html) for recovering your password stored in the saved RDP file.

I always rename the default admin account and use a separate admin account for my admin type of work and keep the original account for emergencies with the password(s) documented elsewhere for emergencies.

Otherwise you might have to resort to booting off media and using a password reset tool to reset the account so that you can re-enable the NIC.

Comment: Thanks, David pointed me to the same site. This software works on RDP files, but the current version of RDC saves passwords as Windows credentials now, and not in the RDP file (see Credentials Manager).